# Locating Lazy Load Elements While Scrolling in PhantomJS in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, webdriver, phantomjs

I'm using python and Webdriver to scrape data from a page that dynamically loads content as the user scrolls down the page (lazy load). I have a total of 30 data elements, while only 15 are displayed without first scrolling down.

I am locating my elements, and getting their values in the following way, after scrolling to the bottom of the page multiple times until each element has loaded:

```
# Get All Data Items
all_data = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[some-attribute="some-attribute-value"]')

# Iterate Through Each Item, Get Value
data_value_list = []
for d in all_data:
    # Get Value for Each Data item
    data_value = d.find_element_by_css_selector('div[class="target-class"]').get_attribute('target-attribute')

    #Save Data Value to List
    data_value_list.append(data_value)
```

When I execute the above code using ChromeDriver, while leaving the browser window up on my screen, I get all 30 data values to populate my `data_value_list`. When I execute the above code using ChromeDriver, with the window minimized, my list `data_value_list` is only populated with the initial 15 data values.

The same issue occurs while using PhantomJS, limiting my `data_value_list` to only the initially-visible data values on the page.

Is there away to load these types of elements while having the browser minimized and, ideally—while utilizing PhantomJS?

NOTE: I'm using an action chain to scroll down using the following approach `.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN).perform()` for a calculated number of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same issue.  The solution I found was to execute javascript code in the virtual browser to force elements to scroll to the bottom.

Before putting the Javascript command into selenium, I recommend opening up your page in Firefox and inspecting the elements to find the scrollable content.  The element should encompass all of the dynamic rows, but it should *not* include the scrollbar  Then, after selecting the element with javascript, you can scroll it to the bottom by setting its scrollTop attribute to its scrollHeight attribute.

Then, you will need to test scrolling the content in the browser.  The easiest way to select the element is by ID if the element has an id, but other ways will work.  To select an element with the id "scrollableContent" and scroll it to the bottom, execute the following code in your browser's javascript console:

```
e = document.getElementById('scrollableContent'); e.scrollTop = e.scrollHeight;
```

Of course, this will only scroll the content to the current top, you will need to repeat this after new content loads if you need to scroll multiple times.  Also, I have no way of figuring out how to find the exact element, for me it is trial and error.

This is some code I tried out.  However, I feel it can be improved, and should be for applications that are intended to test code or scrape unpredictably.  I couldn't figure out how to explicitly wait until more elements were loaded (maybe get the number of elements, scroll to the bottom, then wait for subelement + 1 to show up, and if they don't exit the loop), so I hardcoded 5 scroll events and used time.sleep. time.sleep is ugly and can lead to issues, partly because it depends on the speed of your machine.

```
def scrollElementToBottom(driver, element_id):
 time.sleep(.2)
 for i in range(5):
   driver.execute_script("e = document.getElementById('" + element_id + "'); e.scrollTop = e.scrollHeight;")
   time.sleep(.2)
```

The caveat is that the following solution worked with the Firefox driver, but I see no reason why it shouldn't work with your setup.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I'm able to handle the determination of when to stop scrolling fairly efficiently, I think. Would you mind elaborating a bit further on what you mean by 'scrollable content'? Are you referring to the additional html elements that are loading? So I would basically locate the last one, scroll to it, then locate the next last one—scrolling and repeating until I reached the final element?

Comment: By "scrollable content, I mean the *container* that you can scroll that is holding the elements, not the additional elements.  The code above will not work if you attempt to use it on the last element.  The container should have the additional elements as children.  I will try to make this clearer in my post.

Comment: Ahh, I believe I understand now. I'm away from my computer for awhile now but I will try that approach.